Modeling compounded RFRs with Vasicek
I’m wondering if simple interest rates models, like Vasicek, could be successfully used for modeling compounded setting-in-arrears rates (compounded SOFR for example)?
As far as I see I can do that using monte-carlo as follows:

Generate n paths of instantaneous rates using Vasicek fitted to real data;
For each generated path calculate compounded rates for each date in the path;
Take an average of calculated compounded rates.

Is that approach correct?

I am not familiar with IR simulation, but the approach you suggested using Monte Carlo sounds correct to me.
